# How do I make a for/next loop jump/skip values?

Tags: excel, vba

I want a loop in Excel VBA to iterate through values 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13.

From 1 to 13, skipping 3.

```
Dim i As integer
For i = 1 To 13 "Skip 3"
...
Next i
```

Is that possible?

Comment: `if i <> 3 then` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim i As integer
For i = 1 To 13
    If i <> 3 Then
         'Do stuff
    Else
         'Do nothing, or something else
    End If
Next i
```